# This blog post's title could do with less clickbait!

Tags: discussion, blog

IMHO the recent blog post titled ["How Stack Overflow for Teams Brought This Company’s Leadership and…"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/24/stack-overflow-grandcentrix/) has no reason to use "this company" there. The URL (`https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/24/stack-overflow-grandcentrix/`) itself has the company name, so the obfuscation in the title seems completely unnecessary.

This just feels clickbaity, and Stack Overflow really doesn't need that.

Comment: The secret Stack Exchange doesn't want you to know! [Click here to find out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336891/this-blog-posts-title-could-do-with-less-clickbait) /s

Comment: Amusingly, they do have no qualms about using Facebook's name to attract eyeballs for the other blog post currently featured.

Comment: Sys Admins hate him!

Comment: 5 ways Stack Overflow brought this team closer together. You won't believe #4!

Comment: 1 way this post's title could have done with less clickbait: you won't believe #1!

Comment: I must also have searched closed JIRA tickets in my dreams, because "Documenting [knowledge] in Jira was of no use, because once the ticket was closed, it was just gone. You couldn’t actually research it anymore"

Comment: @Jaco to be somewhat fair - JIRA is sometimes hard to search in. I've encountered it multiple times - I *know* there was some issue logged there but none of the search terms brought it up. If it was solved with code, sometimes the easiest thing was to look through the commit history and find a relevant commit (we embed the JIRA ticket in the message) and use *that* to look up the ticket. Although, I can't say SE search is much better - you still sometimes need the *precise* invocation to bring fourth something otherwise search is useless. I tend to use Google to search SO for dupes.

Comment: @VLAZ I definitely agree that JIRA is hard to search, however, the suggestion that it "was just gone"  appears to be a verifiable inaccuracy. I know marketing material needs to contain a certain level of spin, however, I get immediately put off,  if one of the selling points is simply not true.

Comment: @Jaco I absolutely agree. It's not "gone" but hard to find. Like with search here, you have to know the precise formula to bring it forth - perhaps a fix version, a related tag and you can narrow it down by date or something. Just searching by text might not find it. But that's not *all* issues - some are way easier to find. Again, similar to some posts here. I find the worse thing for searching in JIRA is just how many tickets there are. And a lot aren't even generated by your team, so they might pollute the search space. It's an issue of scale.

Comment: The only problem I've had searching in JIRA, is needing to use the double quotes "" around a search.

Answer (score 30):

The whole post, like many on the blog nowadays, is just an advertisement for Teams. Sadly, it is not disclaimed to be an advertisement (legal?).

It's also a bit weird: who builds a content database in a *chatroom*? Ridiculous comparison.

Anyway, that's why it says "this company" rather than naming said company: the whole post, including its title, is deliberately designed to read like it will also apply to *your* company. That is, probably: [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Is it clickbaity? Yes, yes it is. Welcome to the post-Q&A economy. The blog is no longer a blog.

Comment: I have a policy of not reading the content of posts with clickbait titles (so I only read the first line to confirm that the company name is mentioned). Going from the comments on Jira and what you said, looks like it wasn't a loss at all.

Comment: "*Sadly, it is not disclaimed to be an advertisement (legal?).*" not an expert but I doubt it's illegal. It's the company's blog and they are talking about their own product. It's a bit hard not to "advertise" when you talk about what you've produced. It's just par for the course. Even Joel's blog mentions what he does at his company and makes it sound positive. Is that illegal? Should it be?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know. In my country, regardless of platform ownership, an advertisement has to be clearly identified as such, so as to avoid misleading consumers with false tales of ficticious third-party approval. This may or may not be the case in the illustrious USA.